# Jsp:java.lang.NumberFormatException: null

Tags: java, jsp

**Home.jsp** Post aid to **Edit.jsp**

```
<input type="button" value="修改" onclick="location.href='Edit.jsp?aid=<%=art.getAsId()%>'"/>
```

**Edit.jsp** Get aid.

```
String aid = request.getParameter("aid");
out.print(aid);
if (aid == null) 
    response.sendRedirect("Home.jsp");
else {
    IAsset ad=new AssetDao();
    AssetName art=ad.getInfo(Integer.parseInt(aid));
}
```

**EditControl.jsp**
but in this page, it always tell me aid =null.

```
request.setCharacterEncoding("utf-8");
AssetName art= new AssetName();
art.setAsId(Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("aid")));
art.setUID(request.getParameter("UID"));
art.setAsnu(request.getParameter("asnu"));
art.setAsnm(request.getParameter("asnm"));
art.setAste(request.getParameter("aste"));
art.setSpec(request.getParameter("spec"));
```

And Report

> java.lang.NumberFormatException: null

Comment: I think the problem is art.getAsId(). Are you sure get value?

Comment: It seems art.getAsId() is returning null, that is why you are facing this exception. 
Can you please verify what is returned by art.getAsId()

Comment: The `<input type button>` is inside a `<form>`? And manually typing `Edit.jsp?aid=13` works?

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="button" value="修改" onclick="location.href='Edit.jsp?aid=<%=art.getAsId()%>'"/>
```

In this line **you missed to give name** of the input field
so you need to change it like this

```
<input type="button" name="aid" value="修改" onclick="location.href='Edit.jsp?aid=<%=art.getAsId()%>'"/>
```

and change parsing code like this

```
AssetName art=ad.getInfo(Integer.valueOf(aid));
```